# React-Redux useSelector() not returning the entire string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-hooks

I have some values stored in my Redux global store. However, when I try to retrieve it's values, I get only the first character. I need the entire string from the redux store.

My redux store:

```
path(pin):"https://dog.ceo/api/breed/collie/border/images"
breed(pin):"collie"
subBreed(pin):"border"
```

My code:

```
  const [breed, setBreed] = useSelector((state) => state.breed);
  const [subBreed, setsubBreed] = useSelector((state) => state.subBreed);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Breed in useEffect: ", breed);
    console.log("subBreed in useEffect: ", subBreed);
  }, [breed, subBreed]);
```

The console output:

```
Breed in useEffect:  c
subBreed in useEffect:  b
```

Comment: It seems like you're confusing `useSelector` and `useState`.  What do you get if you use `const breed = useSelector((state) => state.breed);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You are using destructuring assignment to grab out individual characters from a string.

```
const [breed, setBreed] = useSelector((state) => state.breed);
const [subBreed, setsubBreed] = useSelector((state) => state.subBreed);
```

Here `breed` and `subBreed` are the *first* character from each character array, or string.

```js
const [breed, setBreed] = "collie";

console.log({ breed }); // "c" from "collie"
```

## Solution

The `useSelector` hook only returns the state you select, not an array of state and setter. Just assign the selected values to `breed` and `subBreed`.

```
const breed = useSelector((state) => state.breed);
const subBreed = useSelector((state) => state.subBreed);
```

or

```
const { breed, subBreed } = useSelector((state) => state);
```